# Javascript function allow only numbers common and dot

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, function, google-chrome, mozilla

I found function which working IE and Chrome but in Mozilla it isn't working. Maybe someone know why it does not work in Mozilla?

```
function on(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /^[0-9.,]+$/;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it throw and error?

Comment: Looks okay. The error is probably in the HTML which calls this function.

Comment: I mean this function allow write letters in input were I use it but that just happens only in mozilla for other browsers it working. I use onkeypress event in html. Maybe for mozilla need to use other method? or something change?